# My Nvidia 3090 FE insists on running super loud and cool in Ubuntu - how can I change the firmware fan curve?

Tags: gpu, cooling, temperature

[pSensor readout of my GPU fan speeds and temperatures.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0SPN.png)

I've got an Nvidia 3090 FE. Pictured is a readout of my system temperatures (GPU temp is at 58 deg C in red). This screenshot was taken while I was training a LLAMA Lora. As you can see, my computer insists on running the GPU at 58deg C under load, albeit with max fan speed. I'm not sure why this is - i'd much prefer a hotter temperature with a quieter fan speed. No fan curves have been applied with external software. How do I make my GPU prefer a higher temp? Preferably w/ a firmware change or something that doesn't require me to add a start up item to my Ubuntu install.

Thank you.